# Kafka starts throwing replication factor error as soon as spring boot app connects to it

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

Kafka starts flooding logs with the the error

> INFO [Admin Manager on Broker 2]: Error processing create topic request CreatableTopic(name='__consumer_offsets', numPartitions=50, replicationFactor=3, assignments=[], configs=[CreateableTopicConfig(name='compression.type', value='producer'), CreateableTopicConfig(name='cleanup.policy', value='compact'), CreateableTopicConfig(name='segment.bytes', value='104857600')]) (kafka.server.ZkAdminManager)
> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidReplicationFactorException: Replication factor: 3 larger than available brokers: 1.

As soon as the spring boot application connects. Here's the Kafka config I pass via application yaml

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      instanceIndex: 0
      kafka:
        default:
          producer:
            topic:
              replication-factor: 1
            configuration:
              key:
                serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
              spring:
                json:
                  add:
                    type:
                      headers: 'false'
              value:
                serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
              max:
                block:
                  ms: '100'
          consumer:
            topic:
              replication-factor: 1
            configuration:
              key:
                deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
              spring:
                json:
                  trusted:
                    packages: com.message
              value:
                deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
        binder:
          autoCreateTopics: 'false'
          brokers: localhost:19092
          replicationFactor: 1
      bindings:
        consume-in-0:
          group: ${category}-${spring.application.name}-consumer-${runtime-env}
          destination: alm-tom-${runtime-env}
        publish-out-0:
          destination: ${category}-${spring.application.name}-${runtime-env}
```

I don't see any other config to control `consumer-offsets` topic replication factor

Comment: It looks like your broker admin sets the replication-factor to `3` based on your logs in the error. Could you check that with your admin? If that is the case, please look into this section of the ref docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#kafka-binder-properties and look at the replicationFactor property.

Comment: You need to match the proper replication factor set on the broker.

Comment: replication factor is set, at binder level and when that didn't work, at producer and consumer level too as seen in my example. I still get the error. it's trying to create a `__consumer-offset` topic where this happens. I stopped the app and created that topic manually and all works fine now. So I'm intrigued on what's causing spring to create this topic?

Comment: That is a special internal topic created by Kafka itself.

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from the broker itself. It will only start logging this when you create your first consumer group...

Check the `server.properties` file for `offsets.topic.replication.factor`.

Similarly, the transactions topic will have its own replication factor that needs reduced (assuming you're using a newer Kafka version)

Comment: yes it is set to 3, which is why I pass the properties setting offset and transaction log replication to 1, under `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.producerProperties` and `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.consumerProperties` but that didn't help. Still the same error

Comment: Those aren't Kafka client properties. You are required to edit the server configs and restart it